# RSA AES decryption with junk characters

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa, saml

I am trying to decrypt a saml response using AES and RSA, and I could decrypt the saml assertion properly. But, the decrypted text is being embedded in to some junk characters, which is causing parsing exceptions.

Below is my code

```
InputStream privateKeyFileInputStream = Check.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("rsa_privatekey.key"); 
rsaPrivateKey = new byte[privateKeyFileInputStream.available()];
privateKeyFileInputStream.read(rsaPrivateKey);

PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(rsaPrivateKey);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
PrivateKey privKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding", "BC");
cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);

byte[] encryptedMessage = Base64.decodeBase64(aesPrivateKeyEnc.getBytes());
aesPrivateKey = cipher1.doFinal(encryptedMessage);

IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(aesPrivateKey, "AES");
Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "BC");
cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);

byte[] cipherTextBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(cipherText);        
byte[] decryptedMessage = cipher2.doFinal(cipherTextBytes);

String message = new String(decryptedMessage, "UTF8");
```

Now, the message has

```
R����=2�W���?<saml:Assertion ...... </saml:Assertion>��fE]����
```

Comment: You are not preserving the unicode characters, or wherever you are printing the message doesn't have support for displaying them. The console by default does not.

Comment: How can I preserve? The decrypted text (between the junk characters) doesn't have any issues.

Comment: *"How can I preserve?"* - Use UTF-8 everywhere for system interconnect. Its most interoperable. You still might need to convert to a local encoding (like UTF-16 on Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your IV value is prefixed to the ciphertext. Instead of a zero IV you should use the first 16 bytes of your ciphertext for `cipher2`. Don't forget to exclude them from encryption. This explains the garbage at the start.

It also seems that your `cipher2` should be configured for padding. This is probably PKCS#7 padding. Please try `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` instead of `"/NoPadding"`. If that doesn't work you'll need to update your question with the plaintext *in hexadecimals* so we can determine which padding is used. That should explain the garbage at the end.

Note that [`"PKCS5Padding"` does perform PKCS#7 padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172) in Java.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get "Instead of a zero IV you should use the first 16 bytes of your ciphertext for cipher2". And how can I exclude explicitly? 

What about the garbage at the end of the text?

enabling the padding (PKCS5Padding) throwing "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted".

Comment: At `IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);` use the first 16 bytes of `cipherTextBytes`. You can use the `Arrays.copyOfRange` method to split the byte array in two.

Comment: cipherTextBytes has been derived at the end of the code and after ivSpec. Are you referring to some other text?

Comment: No, I'm not. I don't see any problems replacing `new byte[16]` with the first 16 bytes of `cipherTextBytes`. Have you *tried*?

Comment: I made the change as 

IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOfRange(Base64.decodeBase64(cipherText), 0, 16));

which resulted in to "~魨g*(<2�B!@3<saml:Assertion>....</saml:Assertion>��fE]����

Comment: You still need to *split* the ciphertext in two (skip or remove the IV bytes after retrieving them). Could you hex or base 64 encode the decrypted plaintext result and post it here? Random data will lose information if you treat it directly as a string, so it doesn't give us any information.

Comment: I was using "RSA" for the algorithm I changed it to "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" and the problem was solved. No more extra characters

Comment: @steveenzoleko That sounds like a different issue to me. If decryption fails then the result is often just random plaintext.